# Is there anyway to mix ios automation and web automation in a single script using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to perform automation on ios device using selenium web driver and appium. In one scenario I have to create an account and I need to launch the web browser and verify the account and then come back to mobile device and perform the rest of the automation.

Is there anyway to do it? Any reference appreciated

Answer (score 1):

this you can achieve by using certain framework like TestNG (using the priority or dataprovider tags), Selenium Grid, Hybrid driven frame work.

Comment: Thanks @selva..I am using TestNG framework now..is there any reference where I can go through this process..

Comment: @ArunKumar, you can actually do something like
In Priority=0 - do the account creation
In Priority=1 - do the web launching and verification
In Priority=3 - do the mobile automation.

Comment: you can also use Selenium Grid with Appium using testng.xml

Comment: super glad it helped.